<CR> behavior unexpectedly changed in normal mode
I recently made a bunch of changes to my vim configs and I later noticed that the enter/<CR> behavior on normal mode has changed. I used to be able to select and execute a line in the command line window (:q) by selecting it and hitting enter. I believe this to be the default behavior.
But now, when I hit enter, it instead scrolls down by half a screen in both the command window and other buffer windows. I checked my key mappings (:map, :nmap, :nnoremap, etc) but I couldn't find anything setting a mapping for <CR> in normal or any other mode.
How can I figure out what is going on and restore the default behavior?

Ok, I think I figured it out. With the help of vim --clean and :h CR I was able to verify that my old behavior is indeed what the default is. In :h CR I noticed that C-M by default maps to the same behavior. And I recently remapped C-M to scroll a have page. So I deleted that mapping and indeed, I got my default behavior back.
I just need to figure out now how I can remap C-M without also changing CR behavior.

Apparently C-m is CR: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506183/vim-key-mapping-being-fired-by-carriage-return

To get your head twisted a little, there’s also C-j…

Equality of <CR> and <C-M> is documented in :help keycodes. You might also be interested in this answer.

I think you can accept this answer now. Would prevent Community Bot from bumping it every now and then.
